# Unable to get value from JSON by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, load

I am trying to load a JSON data value, which stored on the Google Sheet, into my HTML page.

By now, I am frustrated how to get the value of "12345678" which is under the "gsx$date" and "$t".

However, I am not able to receive the specific value and only the text of `"} //]]>"` was received.

Could someone help me please? Thanks!

For HTML part, I typed the following code for showing the specific json data:

```
<table id="dataTable">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

For Javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript>
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', 'url', true);
xhr.onload = function() 
{
  if (this.status === 200) 
  {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).entry,
            tbodyHtml = '';

    data.map(function(d) {
        tbodyHtml =+ `
        <tr>
            <td>${d.gsx$date.$t}</td>
        </tr>
      `;
    });

    document.querySelector('#dataTable tbody').innerHTML = tbodyHtml;
  }
}
xhr.send();
</script>
```

This is my JSON data from a Google Sheet

```
    { 
   "version":"1.0",
   "encoding":"UTF-8",
   "feed":{ 
      "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
      "xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
      "xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"
      },
      "updated":{ 
         "$t":"2020-02-16T06:28:44.692Z"
      },
      "category":[ 
         { 
            "scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
            "term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
         }
      ],
      "title":{ 
         "type":"text",
         "$t":"Today"
      },
      "openSearch$totalResults":{ 
         "$t":"1"
      },
      "openSearch$startIndex":{ 
         "$t":"1"
      },
      "entry":[ 
         { 
            "updated":{ 
               "$t":"2020-02-16T06:28:44.692Z"
            },
            "category":[ 
               { 
                  "scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                  "term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
               }
            ],
            "title":{ 
               "type":"text",
               "$t":"1"
            },
            "content":{ 
               "type":"text",
               "$t":"time: 2, todayhightemp: 3, todayhightemptime: 4"
            },
            "link":[ 
               { 
                  "rel":"self",
                  "type":"application/atom+xml",
                  "href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/133WezZS498sLEDZ-2ZM_2lvxwcMYwXTiGZPBC0Do0p8/od6/public/full/cokwr"
               }
            ],
            "gsx$date":{
               "$t":"12345678"
            },
            "gsx$time":{ 
               "$t":"23456789"
            },
            "gsx$todayhightemp":{ 
               "$t":"34567890"
            },
            "gsx$todayhightemptime":{ 
               "$t":"45678901"
            },
            "gsx$todaylowtemp":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowtemptime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighrh":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighrhtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowrh":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowrhtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighbar":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighbartime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowbar":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowbartime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighwindspeed":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighwindspeedtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayrainrate":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighrainrate":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighrainratetime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayet":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighsolarradiation":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighsolarradationtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighuv":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighuvtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighdewpoint":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighdewpointtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowdewpoint":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todaylowdewpointtime":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighheatindex":{ 
               "$t":""
            },
            "gsx$todayhighheatindextime":{ 
               "$t":""
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Load everything as JSON. 
So to achieve it please follow [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cjn-google-sheets-as-json-endpoint/) tutorial to retrieve all of the sheet as JSON. When I was following the tutorial, my **GOOGLESHEETCODE** was the code, generated from shared button on the top right corner.

2) Use fetch or axios to make the request.

Here is an example with `fetch`:

```
const url = 'YOUJSONENDPOINTURL';


fetch(url)
    .then(data=> data.json())
    .then(result => {
        let firstCell = result['feed']['entry'][0]['gsx$date']['$t'];

        result['feed']['entry'].forEach((b) => { // loop through all cells
           console.log(b.gsx$date.$t);
        })
    })
```

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` as it is from your request.
The issue in your example is that the JSON that you've attached is invalid and that is not the same JSON structure that we are retrieving from sheets.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I follow the tutorial completely and finally got a json url. However, I tried with your code but still unsuccessful. Would you please take a look for my code? Thank you in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/ze1ro5vg/

Comment: Remove the `<script>` tags and `} //]]>` will disappear.